# cruise control turns off on me when i use the system process

Tags: windows, cruisecontrol.net

Cruise control service set to System - Allow user to interact with desktop for the service.

I log out with my user id and cruise control turns off.

Any idea what is going on here?

If I start the service a console window comes up.  As soon as I close it cruise control also turns off...

I need it to always be on... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start Cruise Control.NET from the Services.msc. 
You can configure Cruise Control.NET to use your own username and password to logon to windows when its service starts.
You may also want to start the service automatically.